# Java nested class does not recognize instance of itself

Tags: java, linked-list, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a linked list, but for some reason the `Link<E>` class does not 'recognize' (for a lack of better words) an instance of itself. More specifically VS code tells me: `The method setnext(Problem<E>.Link<E>) is undefined for the type Problem<E>.Link<E>`. I believe this means it sees linkToAdd as an instance of `Problem<E>.Link<E>` and itself as an instance of `Link<E>`. But I might be misunderstanding.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a minimized version of the class that still produces the error:

```java
public class Problem<E>
{
    public class Link<E>
    {
        private E element;
        private Link<E> next;

        Link(E element, Link<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

        void setNext(Link<E> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Link<E> start;

    public Problem() {
        start = new Link<E>(null, null);
    }

    public boolean add(E element) {
        Link<E> linkToAdd = new Link<E>(element, null);
        this.start.setnext(linkToAdd); 
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have added the constructor for the problem class. There is no main(String[] args) as this is part of a school exercise and I am only given the documentation of a class and am expected to create said class based on that. I am not actually using this class anywhere yet.

EDIT #2: This is the error given by running `java Problem.java` in a terminal:

```
Problem.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        this.start.setnext(linkToAdd); 
                  ^
  symbol:   method setnext(Problem<E>.Link<E>)
  location: variable start of type Problem<E>.Link<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Problem
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

Comment: Please include the complete compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was just a typo:** setNext() was capitalized in the `Link<E>` class definition but not in add() method where I used setnext().

Looking back this is actually what vs code was trying to tell me all along:

`The method setnext(Problem<E>.Link<E>) is undefined for the type Problem<E>.Link<E>`

However I got confused by the use of `Link<E>` everywhere and seemed to have confused the rest of us by sharing my wrong interpretation of the error. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not provide your client (driver) code, I assume you are not instantiating Link correctly. Please see valid example.

```
public class Problem<E> {
        class Link<E> {
            private E element;
            private Link<E> next = null;

            public Link(E element) {
                this.element = element;
            }

            public void setnext(Link<E> next) {
                this.next = next;
            }
        }

        Link<E> start = new Link(null);

        public void add(E element) {
            Link<E> linkToAdd = new Link(element);
            start.setnext(linkToAdd);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Problem<Integer> problem = new Problem<>();
            Problem<Integer>.Link<Integer> link = problem.new Link<Integer>(1);
            problem.add(2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested class isn't recognized because you need to create first an object of `Problem` type to instantiate a `Link` object. You need to set your nested class `static` in order to make `Link<E> start = new Link(null)` work.

```
public class Bar {
 public class Foo {
     int a, b;

     void doSomething() {
         System.out.println(a + " " + b);
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Bar bar = new Bar();
     Foo foo = bar.new Foo();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The code in the comment creates a new `Node` within an instance method, thus it automatically binds to the surroinding object.

Comment: QUOTE : "Here is a minimized version of the class that still produces the error:" . I'm assuming that the Link<> start = new Link<>() is in a `public static void main` method. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Don't post speculative answers. Ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: I can remove it if it's not ok.